# How can you set the background color of a bevy entity?

Tags: rust, bevy

I have a rapier2d project featuring a falling box, how can I make the falling box not have the debug renderer and have a solid black color? And then, how can I make a solid colored circle/triangle/other shapes?

I tried using a NodeBundle with a background color, but it did not work.

I tried using a BackgroundColor(Color::BLACK), but it did not work.

By not work I mean that it does not show anything